# Ionic will not run after upgrade

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework, npm, gulp

I am building an app using Ionic Framework and AngularJS 1.x

A couple weeks ago I upgraded my ionic cli to version 2.0.0. Today, I found that I cannot run `$ionic serve` or `$ionic build` it was giving some error about not being able to find gulp though I could confirm that gulp was indeed installed and running. This problem was only happening in one ionic 1.x project, other ionic 1.x projects were working fine.

I attempted to fix the issue by upgrading node (I was using version 0.12.x) and now I am on version 6.6.0.

But now ionic will not run any ionic command, it instead returns an error:

```
 $ ionic
Caught exception:
 Error: Cannot find module 'inherits'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:455:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:403:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/glob/glob.js:42:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3) 

Mind letting us know? https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues
```

This error is happening even in projects that were unaffected but the previous problem.

Please help. I am on linux Mint 17.1

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to resolve the issue by reinstalling ionic & cordova as well as making sure, node, nodejs, npm, bower and gulp were all up to date. This got ionic working but I still could not run old ionic 1.x projects getting an error that gulp could not be found.

To resolve this, delete the `node_modules` directory in your project folder and run `$ npm install`